# How to use a Swift class from C++ in Swift 5.9 and Xcode 15

Tags: c++, swift

I am experimenting with the new C++ / Swift interoperability in swift 5.9 but am having difficulty with creating and using a Swift class from the C++ side.

I have a simple command line project called ‘Test’.

On the Swift side in main I have:

```
import Foundation

setup()

public func callback(){
    
}


public class SwiftClass{
    
    init(){}

    func doSomething(){}
}
```

And on the C++ side I have:

```
#include "Test-Swift.h"

using namespace Test;

void setup(void){
    callback();
     
    SwiftClass obj = SwiftClass();// Error:No matching constructor for initialization of 'SwiftClass'
}
```

Xcode automatically creates a Test-Swift.h file and there is also a bridging header that includes the C++ header file.

When I run this, the callback works fine, however I don't seem to be able to create an instance of the SwiftClass.

Can someone show me how I can create a Swift object within the C++ setup() function and call its doSomething method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the Swift side:

```
public class SwiftClass{
    
    public init(){}

    public func doSomething(){}
}
```

on the C++ side:

```
SwiftClass obj = SwiftClass::init();
obj.doSomething();
```